# Beautifulsoup is returning an empty list while trying to access img link

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've tried to play around with the code to find the links. I've narrowed down the HTML to find the relevant images and retreive them all. However, it's returning an empty list.
I can't seem to understand where the problem actually.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get('https://www.f1-fansite.com/f1-wallpaper/wallpaper-photos-2022-canadian-f1-grand-prix/', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

pictureslist = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': 'gallery-1',
                            'class': 'gallery galleryid-268780 gallery-columns-3 gallery-size-medium'})

print(pictureslist)
```

Am I looking at the right place to fetch all image links?

Comment: When I fetch that page, the string "268780" does not appear.  It is possible they are creating those numbers dynamically, to prevent people from stealing their copyrighted material.  Try without that class name.

Comment: the div containing images has id "gallery-1". the "gallerid-######" tag is irrellevant. Once you have the div, each image is contained in that div via the class "gallery-item".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select all the gallery-items `a` and extract the `href`:

```
set(e.get('href') for e in soup.select('.gallery-item a'))
```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get('https://www.f1-fansite.com/f1-wallpaper/wallpaper-photos-2022-canadian-f1-grand-prix/', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

set(e.get('href') for e in soup.select('.gallery-item a'))
```

###### Output

```
{'https://www.f1-fansite.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/1019217025-LAT-20220619-GP2209_123003_ONZ8707-725.jpg',
 'https://www.f1-fansite.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/1019217091-LAT-20220619-GP2209_171345_AF_1474-712.jpg',
 'https://www.f1-fansite.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/1019217141-LAT-20220619-GP2209_180413_56I3103-923.jpg',
 'https://www.f1-fansite.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/1019217158-LAT-20220619-GP2209_172751_AF_1595-561.jpg',
 'https://www.f1-fansite.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/1019217306-SUT-20220619-GP2209_190245DSC_3459-725.jpg',
 'https://www.f1-fansite.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/17-sunday-canada-2022.jpg',
 'https://www.f1-fansite.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/18-sunday-canada-2022.jpg',
 'https://www.f1-fansite.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/19-sunday-canada-2022.jpg',
 'https://www.f1-fansite.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/20-sunday-canada-2022.jpg',
 'https://www.f1-fansite.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/2022-Canadian-Grand-Prix-Friday-1.jpg',...}
```